# Не отображаются заказы в админке minishop2

Tags: php, modx, minishop2

Установлен MODX Revolution 2.7.3-pl, установлен плагин minishop2.
Проблема в следующем заказы создаются добавляются в базу данных,  но не отображаются в таблице заказов в админке, при всем этом отображается общая сумма заказов. Смотрел логи, никаких ошибок не возникает при загрузке этой страницы.

[image: Страница Заказов]

Comment: получилось что-нибудь решить с вашим вопросом?